# Crash when invoking popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO, set animate to YES work no crash, strange.

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, crash

My app is based on UINavigationViewController, there are 3 ViewController in the stack, named A, B, C,  A is root view controller, now in ViewController C do the following operation, app will crash 100%.

```
- (void) delayPopAction {
    [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}

- (void)searchTap:(id)sender{
    [self performSelector:@selector(delayPopAction) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
}
```

Trace by zombie and find the crash dues to C has been destroyed but there is still event available sent to him. More strange, if I change animated parameter from NO to YES, no crash happen, maybe dues to C's life circle has been enlarged.

See API doc. How does NO mean? I don't understand it clearly.
animated
Set this value to YES to animate the transition. Pass NO if you are setting up a navigation controller before its view is displayed.

Any idea or suggestion will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it is my view-controller implementation defect.